# Cannot connect to Raspberry Pi 3 through Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, permissions, ssh, ethernet, sd-card

Standard new Raspberry Pi 3 Starter Kit with Keyboard, Mouse, Micro SD Card.

No screen available that is why first connection is planned through Ethernet cable.

Tried to connect on Ubuntu (two different laptops) and Windows 10.

MicroSD card preparation:

Earlier trials:
Raspbian installed by Win32 DiskImager then tried on Windows and Linux.

Later trials (actually just ONE trial on Ubuntu):

Tried to install Noobs on SD Card on Linux by: Downloading Noobs package, unpacking with basic Ubuntu extraction tool and copying all the files on Micro SD card (formatted by GParted to fat32) Result: permission denied

Trials to run Raspberry:

To connect to Raspberry on Windows I have tried Putty (port 22, all passwords as in tutorials).

To connect on Ubuntu

```
ssh pi@<host_ip>
```

Results were similar.

- Ubuntu -> permission denied
- Windows -> something similar

Ping trial:

- Windows : Ok
- Ubuntu 1: Ok
- Ubuntu 2: Around 20% lost

How could I check whether the file system is installed in a properly?

Comment: I'm not sure how your question relates to Ubuntu. As far as I understand there's no Ubuntu running on the machine in question. Could you pleas explain? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE], [RaspberryPi.SE], or more generally [SU].

Comment: Off topic. Thanks. The only relation there is is really not that important.

Answer (score 2):

By default, on newer Rasp OS's, SSH is disabled by default (security measure)

**1. Burn the image**

```
dd bs=4M if=2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/mmc
```

Where, **/dev/mmc** is the name of your SD card. You can get that info from:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

**2. Enable SSH**

To enable SSH, and set it up heedlessly, create an empty file named **ssh** in your boot partition of SD card.

**3. Check DHCP**

Make sure that DHCP is enabled on the router, and connect via Ethernet.

**4. Find the IP of raspi**

Either connect to the router and check, or run *fping* or *nmap* and scan your network.

Should work with no problems.

Comment: See also : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: Working. More networking knowledge was required.